# TarsosDSP in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, tarsosdsp

This is my first post on SO and I am trying to combine my music skills with computer science.

I am using Android studio 3.1.2 with gradle 4.5, Nexus 5X, API 25, Android 7.1.1, Windows 7.
I followed very careful these instructions:

1. Create a project called Pitchbender
2. Download the `.jar` of TarsosDSP and included in

   ```
   C:\Users\Carlos\AndroidStudioProjects\Pitchbender\app\libs\TarsosDSP-Android-latest
   ```
3. I checked the `build.gradle` of my project:

   ```
   dependencies { implementation fileTree(dir: ‘libs’, include: [‘*.jar’]) }
   ```
4. In my project, I have the following imports automatically done by *Android Studio*:

   ```
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
   import android.os.Bundle
   import android.view.View
   import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioEvent
   import be.tarsos.dsp.io.android.AudioDispatcherFactory
   import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchDetectionHandler
   import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchDetectionResult
   import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchProcessor
   import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
   import be.tarsos.dsp.pitch.PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm
   import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioProcessor
   import android.widget.TextView
   import be.tarsos.dsp.AudioDispatcher
   ```
5. I have this permission in my manifest file

   ```
   uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO”
   ```
6. *Android Studio* gives the option to convert to Kotlin the first line of the following code:

   ```
   AudioDispatcher dispatcher =  AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);
   ```

   If I respond to “No” to the Kotlin conversion, I have the following compilation error:

   > Clasifier “AudioDispatcher” does not have any companion object, and thus must be initialized here.

   What can I do?

   If I respond “Yes” to the Kotlin conversion question, that statement is converted to

   ```
   val dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050, 1024, 0)
   ```

   and then, when I run this program, Android informs me that there is an error and closes my project and keeps closing my project. What to do?

Please help to run at least that first instruction of the complete code:

```
PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e){
        final float pitchInHz = res.getPitch();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                processPitch(pitchInHz);
            }
        });
    }
};
AudioProcessor pitchProcessor = new PitchProcessor(PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);

Thread audioThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Thread");
audioThread.start();
```

**Question:**

Do you have any simple project in *Android Studio*, so that I can see what my errors are?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I tried to run this example and my solution (Sep. 2019) was to add a runtime confirmation of the record permission. I'm not sure if it's the same case, buuuut

Here is my code to it:

```java
private boolean permissionToRecordAccepted = false;
    private String [] permissions = {Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
    private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION = 200;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION:
                permissionToRecordAccepted  = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                break;
        }
        if (!permissionToRecordAccepted ) finish();
    }
```